# How to set a property of a service from an async method in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I have a service and a component as follows:

```
import {OnDestroy, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { JumpService } from "./jump-service";
@Component({
  selector: 'jumper',
  providers: [JumpService]
})
export class Jump implements OnDestroy {
   constructor(
        private _jumpService: JumpService
    ) {

    }
private async _JumpAndShoot(): Promise<area51.armor> {
        let oxy = await this._panic;
        if (!oxy) return;
        this._jumpService.armour = { a, b };
        this._jumpService.oxy = oxy;
        return { a, b };
    }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class JumpService {

     armor: area51.armor;
     oxy: area51.oxylevel;

shoot() {
 //logic
 console.log("Value of oxy", this.oxy); // shows undefined.
}

}
```

Even though, the value of `oxy` is set on the `JumpService` inside the async method, it is always shown as `undefined` in my service when I try to access it. Whereas I don't have problem accessing the armor property which is being set in the method. Is there any different way of setting the properties when dealing with `async` methods? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you "shooting"? And when?

Comment: I have a different component in which I have the JumpService injected. From there, on a click, I am calling a method in which I trigger shoot() as "this.jumpService.shoot()".

Comment: When you iject your service like `providers: [JumpService]` you make local dependency for your component and it tree. Does the second component in this tree? Why service not in a main module?

Comment: I see what you are saying. My service is in the main module and still I was adding the provider. I removed the provider and it worked! WOW. Thanks a lot @LyubimovRoman Please write an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using providers in a component like `@Component(providers: [JumpService])`it will be local to this component and its tree. Provide it in your main module or a top level component.